# Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

Este código lo descargué de un tutorial en *Youtube* y funciona, solo que este emite unas alerts **(Que están dentro de un DIV HTML)** cuando un email se envía/o faltan datos, SÍ MUESTRA LAS ALERTS, pero cada que carga la página sale:

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in /public_html/kontakto/index.php on line 60

¿Me podrían decir que está mal?:

Tengo PHP v7.3 y cabe resaltar que es un `<?php ?>` seguido del `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Este es el div (Y donde da el error):

```
<div id="error"><?php echo $successMsg ?><?php echo $error ?><?php echo $captchaFail ?></div>
```

Y éste el código PHP:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['ContactButton'])) {
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $privateKey = "";
        $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privateKey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        $data = json_decode($response);
        if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true) {
            $error = "";
            $successMsg = "";
            if ($_POST) {
                if ($_POST['email'] && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
                    $error .= "The email is invalid!<br>";
                }
                if (!$_POST['email']) {
                    $error .= "An email address is required!<br>";
                }
                if (!$_POST['subject']) {
                    $error .= "A subject is required!<br>";
                }
                if (!$_POST['body']) {
                    $error .= "Content in the body is required!<br>";
                }
                if ($error != "") {
                    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>There is an error with your form!</strong><br>' . $error . '</div>';
                } else {
                    $emailTo = 'CONTACT FORM DELIVERY EMAIL';
                    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
                    $body = $_POST['body'];
                    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['email'];
                    if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                        $successMsg = '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">The message has successfully been sent. We will contact you ASAP!</div>';
                    } else {
                        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">There was a problem sending your message, please try again later!</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $captchaFail = '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong>There is an error with your form!</strong><br>reCaptcha Verification Failed, Please Try Again.</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Y aquí una screenshot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme dado a explicar bien, muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: Saludos. Te comento; lo que ocurre es que durante el tiempo de vida del Script *php* no hay un momento antes de esas parte (del `div`) en los que previamente fuesen inicializadas las variables `$successMsg` y `$error`. Toda variable que va a ser usada, debes cerciorarte sea inicializada (en su contexto) de alcance para evitar ese u otros errores.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicarme amigo! Ya pude solucionarlo con la respuesta de abajo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `isset` en el div de la siguiente manera:

```
<div id="error">
   <?php echo isset($successMsg) ? $successMsg : '' ?>
   <?php echo isset($error) ? $error : '' ?>
   <?php echo isset($captchaFail) ? $captchaFail : ''  ?>
</div>
```

Lo que hace esto es validar si existe la variable que estas mandado, por ejemplo, si todo el proceso sale bien, se enviara el mensaje de `$successMsg` pero las demás no y saldrá el error de variable indefinida, `isset` valida su fueron declaradas y además verifica si no son nulas.

Puedes ver mas información de esta función en la documentación de [php](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! De verdad, me funcionó perfectamente

Comment: La otra opción, y más corta, es mover la declaración de las variables `$successMsg`, `$error` y `$captchaFail` más arriba, fuera del primer `if`, así siempre estarán definidas y no dará error, pero estarán en blanco con lo cual no mostrarán ningún mensaje al usuario.